# How to send a mail from a form and show a popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

## What I want to achieve

To send an email from an HTML form and show a popup to tell the user whether the input is valid.

## Background

I'm developing a website where users can input their email addresses on a contact form and submit it to a certain email address. Besides, I want to show a popup to let the users know whether the input email address is valid i.e. not empty in this case.

Here's a diagram to show what it's like.

[image]

The procedure in detail is as follows.

1. A user inputs an email address in a form
2. The user clicks a submit button
3. If the email address is valid i.e. not empty, it is sent to a certain email address then a popup is shown to tell the user the email address was successfully sent.
4. If the email address is empty, a popup with an error message should be shown.

The flowchart is below.

[image]

After hours of searching, I decided to implement the features above as follows.

For user input, `<form>` and `action` attribute will be used like:

```
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
  Email <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To send a mail, `mail()` function in PHP will be used like:

```
<?php
$sender = 'from@websiteform.com';
$recipient = 'recipient@recip.com';
$subject = "from website";
$message = $_POST['email'];
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)
?>
```

And the code for a popup is as follows.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#gray-panel{
background : #000;
opacity  : 0.5;
width  : 100%;
height  : 99999;
position : fixed;
top   : 0;
left  : 0;
display  : none;
z-index  : 50;
}

#popup{
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
border: solid 2px black;
background: yellow;
display: none;
z-index : 51;
position: fixed;
top: 70;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<div id="gray-panel"></div>
<div id="popup">this is a pop up window!<div>

<script>
var left_position = $("body").width()/2 - $("#popup").width()/2;
$("#gray-panel").fadeIn("slow");
$("#popup")
    .css("left", left_position)
    .fadeIn("slow");

$("#popup").click(function(){
    $( "#gray-panel" ).fadeOut("slow");
    $( "#popup" ).fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

But there are a few problems.

1. the user is sent to a new page after clicking the submit button. I'd like to show a popup in the same page. I googled "form action  php not transition" but couldn't find any useful resource.
2. jQuery for a popup can't be called from PHP since they are on different pages. `echo "<script> function(); </script>";` or `echo "<script src=\"popup.js\"></script>";` doesn't seem to be applicable in this case.

What should I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: #1: Use Ajax to send the email address to PHP. You'll need to prevent the normal form submit with `preventDefault()`. #2 You will be able to show the popup on Ajax success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your first issue you will need to submit the form via AJAX. This will prevent the page from refreshing.

To do this you will need `jQuery` which i can see you are already using which is excellent. To make a basic AJAX call you will want to do something like this:

This code basically does the following: When the form has been submitted, it prevents the page from being refreshed using `event.preventDefault();` and then sends the following data to the script specified using a `post` request.

```
  jQuery('.sign-up-form').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         url  : '/path/to/file.php',
         data : jQuery('.sign-up-form').serialize(),
         beforeSend: function(){
         jQuery("#error").fadeOut();
      },
         success :  function(response){
           var left_position = $("body").width()/2 - $("#popup").width()/2;
           $("#gray-panel").fadeIn("slow");
           $("#popup").css("left", left_position).fadeIn("slow");
         }
      });
  });
```

Please note you will need to add the `sign-up-form` class to your form to make it look like this:

```
  <form class="sign-up-form" method="post">
    Email <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

For functionalilty for verifying email addresses you will need to add some extra logic into your php file (dependant on how far you need to verify). If it is just to make sure what has been sent is in the email format then you will see i have changed your input from type `text` to type `email`.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to prevent default form submission with this

```
$(".form").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
```

i suggest you use sweet alert plugin if you don't want to get you hands dirty with css, if you are using sweet alerts then your ajax code should be like this:

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure you want to send us a mail?",
    text: "You will get a feedback in 24hrs",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function (isConfirm) {
    if (!isConfirm) return;
$.ajax({type: "post",
        url: "sendmail.php",
        data: $('.form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            var strres =JSON.stringify(res);
            console.log(strres);
            if(strres === '"Sent"'){
                swal("Sent" ,"Email sent sucessfully" ,"success");
            }
            else{
                swal( "An error occurred!!!", "Please try again" ,"error");
            }
       }
   });

    });
});
```

then your html will be:

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    Email <input type="email" name="email" pattern="^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$" required">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

then you can further do you validation and sending in php.

I hope this helps you.